# Strange Error in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have written a formula to calculate the x and y speed of an object following another object given that I want speed to = 5.

Perhaps I am just being and idiot and my working is incorrect but when I try to run the flash game it compiles but gets a run time error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
    at avoiderv2_fla::MainTimeline/anenemyMovement()
```

This is the calculation I am using (yes I have defiantly tracked the issue back to this particular line)

```
e.target.ndx = (Math.sin((Math.asin(e.target.dx(Math.sin(90)/e.target.speed)))*180/Math.PI)*(e.target.speed/Math.sin(90)))
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`...e.target.dx(Math.sin(90)...` portion looks suspicios. Are you sure dx is a function?

I think it should be `...e.target.dx * (Math.sin(90)...` or something similar (notice `*`).

Comment: Thankyou, that worked :) Sorry I should have specified, dx and ndx are variables, I didn't think I would need a * as I thought actionscript would take it for granted it was multiplying but apparently not. Thanks

Comment: All languages in common use requre you to specify operator (usually `*`) for multiplcation. Complexity that comes from trying to specify/parse language that allows `a x` or even `ax` to be treated as multiplication of `a` and `x` is too high to be safe and useful in general-purpose language.

Comment: Well the calculation worked anyway, there is still something wrong with it as it always returns 1, guess I got some math wrong, I will take a better look